# ¿Por qué me rompe la aplicación y se me cierra cuando ejecuto t=new Tipo(); t->show();?

Tags: c++, qt

```
#include "tipo.h"

#include <QWidget>
#include <QDialog>
#include "elemento.h"

Tipo::Tipo(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
   // Tipo::setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/config/images/logos/diseño.png"));
    Tipo::setWindowTitle("Crear Tipo-Subtipo");

    mainLayout=new QVBoxLayout(this);

    verticalLayout=new  QVBoxLayout();

    labelTipo= new QLabel();

    labelTipo->setText( tr( "Nombre"  ));
    labelTipo->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    lineTipo = new QLineEdit();
    lineTipo->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    labelId= new QLabel();

    labelId->setText( tr( "IdTipo"  ));
    labelId->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    lineId = new QLineEdit();
    lineId->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    labelSubtipo->setText( tr( "Subtipo"  ));
    labelSubtipo->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    lineSubtipo = new QLineEdit();
    lineSubtipo->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    labelIdSubtipo= new QLabel();

    labelIdSubtipo->setText( tr( "IdSubtipo"  ));
    labelIdSubtipo->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    lineIdSubtipo = new QLineEdit();
    lineIdSubtipo->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    btnGuardar= new QPushButton();
    btnGuardar->setText( tr( "Guardar"  ) );

    verticalLayout->addWidget(labelId);
    verticalLayout->addWidget(lineId);
    verticalLayout->addWidget(labelTipo);
    verticalLayout->addWidget(lineTipo);
    verticalLayout->addWidget(labelIdSubtipo);
    verticalLayout->addWidget(lineIdSubtipo);
    verticalLayout->addWidget(labelSubtipo);
    verticalLayout->addWidget(lineSubtipo);
    verticalLayout->addWidget(btnGuardar);

    mainLayout->addLayout(verticalLayout);

    connect(btnGuardar, SIGNAL (clicked()), this, SLOT (on_btnGuardar_clicked()));
}

void Tipo::on_btnGuardar_clicked()
{
    QString nombre=lineTipo->text();
    int id=(lineId->text()).toInt();
    int idSub=(lineIdSubtipo->text()).toInt();
    QString nomSub=lineSubtipo->text();
    QSqlQuery q2;
    q2.exec(QString("SELECT count( id_subtipo) FROM subtipo WHERE id_subtipo=%1;").arg(idSub));
    q2.first();
    if((q2.value(0)).toInt()==0) {
        QSqlQuery q3;
        q3.prepare("INSERT INTO subtipo(id_subtipo,nombre) VALUES(?,?)");
        q3.addBindValue(idSub);
        q3.addBindValue(nomSub);

        bool ok=q3.exec();
        if(!ok){

            QSqlError mError=q3.lastError().text();
            qDebug()<<mError;
        }
    }

    QSqlQuery q4;
    q4.prepare("INSERT INTO tipo(id_tipo,nombre,id_subtipo) VALUES(?,?,?)");
    q4.addBindValue(id);
    q4.addBindValue(nombre);
    q4.addBindValue(idSub);
    bool ok=q4.exec();
    if(!ok){

        QSqlError mError=q4.lastError().text();
        qDebug()<<mError;
    }
    emit acabado();
    close();
}

#ifndef TIPO_H
#define TIPO_H

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>


class Tipo : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Tipo(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Tipo(){}



    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout;
    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout;
    QLabel *labelTipo;
    QLabel *labelId;
    QLabel *labelSubtipo;
    QLabel *labelIdSubtipo;
    QPushButton *btnGuardar;
    QLineEdit *lineId;
    QLineEdit *lineTipo;
    QLineEdit *lineSubtipo;
    QLineEdit *lineIdSubtipo;
signals:

void acabado();
private slots:

void on_btnGuardar_clicked();
private:



};

#endif // TIPO_H
```

** `t=new Tipo(); t->show(); esto va en el mainWindow*`*

Comment: en MaindowWindow declare class Tipo y Tipo *t;

Comment: Los comentarios no se usan para añadir información relevante a la pregunta, edita la pregunta... y por favor, compacta y tabula un poco ese código

Comment: Sólo veo `t=new Tipo();` y `t->show();` en el título, no en las 172 líneas de código que has pegado.

Comment: Por favor, pon la función correspondiente de `mainWindow` **completa** o bueno, si hay alguna parte que puedas eliminar de dicha función y que el error se siga reproduciendo...

Answer (score 0):

labelSubtipo no lo había declarado.